# Remove rows below first occurrence of a particular value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

The goal is to identify when `c` and `d` in `code`, per unique `ID`, occurs after `a` and then subset the dataframe (subsetting the groupby would be just as good) to not include those `ID`s.

Sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.repeat([1,2,3],[3,4,3]), 'dates' : [(pd.Timestamp('2018-12-30 00:00:00') + pd.Timedelta(hr, unit = 'h')) for hr in range(10)], 'cd': ['c','b','a','b','c','a','c','b','a','d']})

grouped = df.groupby('ID', as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('dates', ascending = False))

grouped = grouped.groupby('ID')
```

With this dataset, `ID==2` and `ID==3` should be removed from the df:

```
for key, item in grouped:
    print(grouped.get_group(key), "\n\n")
```

Output:

```
     ID               dates cd
0 2   1 2018-12-30 02:00:00  a
  1   1 2018-12-30 01:00:00  b
  0   1 2018-12-30 00:00:00  c 


     ID               dates cd
1 6   2 2018-12-30 06:00:00  c
  5   2 2018-12-30 05:00:00  a
  4   2 2018-12-30 04:00:00  c
  3   2 2018-12-30 03:00:00  b 


     ID               dates cd
2 9   3 2018-12-30 09:00:00  d
  8   3 2018-12-30 08:00:00  a
  7   3 2018-12-30 07:00:00  b
```

I think the following accomplishes this goal where it creates a string per group and then uses `str.find()` to determine precedence:

```
for i,r in grouped:
    cdSeq = ''
    for code in r['cd']:
        cdSeq+=code
    if abs(cdSeq.find('c')) < abs(cdSeq.find('a')) or abs(cdSeq.find('d'))<abs(cdSeq.find('a')):
        df = df[df['ID']!=i]

df.groupby('ID', as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('dates', ascending = False))
```

Output:

```
       ID                 dates cd
0   2   1   2018-12-30 02:00:00  a
    1   1   2018-12-30 01:00:00  b
    0   1   2018-12-30 00:00:00  c
```

Is there a more succinct, efficient, and/or pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for accepting the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine what rows appear after "a" per group as `u`. Then, determine what rows contain "c" and "d", as `v`. Using `mul`, we determine what rows fit our criteria, and then use `groupby` and `any` to get a mask to eliminate them.

```
u = df['cd'].eq('a').groupby(df.ID).cumsum()
v = df['cd'].isin(['c', 'd'])

df[~u.mul(v).groupby(df.ID).transform('any')]

   ID               dates cd
0   1 2018-12-30 00:00:00  c
1   1 2018-12-30 01:00:00  b
2   1 2018-12-30 02:00:00  a
```